# Neo4j Cypher round value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Cypher:

```
MATCH (v:Value)-[:CONTAINS]->(hv:HistoryValue) 
WHERE v.id = {valueId} 
OPTIONAL MATCH (hv)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
WHERE {fetchCreateUsers} 
WITH u, hv ORDER BY hv.createDate DESC 
WITH count(hv) as count, count(hv) / {maxResults} as step, COLLECT({userId: u.id, historyValueId: hv.id, historyValue: hv.originalValue, historyValueCreateDate: hv.createDate}) AS data 
RETURN REDUCE(s = [], i IN RANGE(0, count - 1, CASE step WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE step END) | s + data[i]) AS result, step, count
```

right now:

```
count(hv)  = 260
{maxResults} = 100
```

The `step` variable equals 2 but I expect `round(260/100)` = 3

I tried the following `round(count(hv) / {maxResults}) as step` but `step` is still 2.

How to fix my query in order to get a proper round (3 as `step` variable in this particular case)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [toFloat()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-tofloat) in one of the values:

```
return round(toFloat(260) / 100)
```

Output:

```
╒═══════════════════════════╕
│"round(toFloat(260) / 100)"│
╞═══════════════════════════╡
│3                          │
└───────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Beat me to it :-). Actually, its enough to convert one of the numbers to float (e.g. `round(count(hv) / toFloat({maxResults})) as step`)

Comment: Thanks @GaborSzarnyas! Edited! :)

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to round the values like for example 2.3 to 3 as well and not to 2?

Comment: @alexanoid you are welcome! I think you are looking for the [ceil() function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/mathematical/numeric/#functions-ceil). `return ceil(2.3)` will output 3.

Answer (score 3):

You're currently doing integer division. If you enter `return 260/100` you'll get `2`, and that's the value that gets rounded (though there's nothing to round, so you get `2` back).

You need to be working with floating point values. You can do this by having `maxResults` have an explicit decimal (`100.0`), or use `toFloat()` around either `maxResults` or the count. Both `return 260/100.0` and `return toFloat(260)/100` or `return 260/toFloat(100)` will result in 2.6. If you `round()` that you'll get your expected `3` value.